# What's the best index for a json fields checking and fields range queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Suppose we have the following table:

I have the following object:

`struct Tick = {
   country  string
   region   string
   type     string
   spec     map string -> int  # {v1: n1, v2:n2}
   t        timestamp
}`

I want to store this objects in **Posgresql 9.4**. There will be millions of them. 
90% of queries will involve:

- `type`
- a combination of `country` / `region` (both, one or none)
- `t` range (most of the will be just `t > tx`)

All above query combinations are evenly distributed.
Then about 5% will additionally involve checking spec attributes: existence or range.

**What's the best way to encode such object in Postgresql 9.4 and which index should be created?**

Few ideas:

1. encode all fields as a single string and make a regex queries. Eg: `encoded = "type;country;v1:n1;v2:n2"`. Then, is it possible to make an compound index `(t, encoded)`, which will allow for range queries on `t` and regexp queries on `encoded`?  In this approach we dismiss spec range checking in index,
2. encode everything in `jsonb`. Then, is it possible to make an index range queries on some jsonb attributes?

[EDIT]
Ad. 1. Instead of encoding this values in a single string, one can put them in a table (`tab = {type, country, v1+n1, ...}`) and create gin index: `gin (t timestamp_ops, tab _text_ops)` using [btree_gini](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gin.html) extension.

Comment: What forbid you to use a simple Tick table with 5 fields and classic indexes ?

Comment: In "classic" index: `(a,b,c,d)` I can't query for `c` without specifying both `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple. Use a conventional table and a composite index.

I'd be looking at something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE blah (
  country text,
  region text,
  type text,
  spec json,
  t timestamp not null
);
```

There's no obvious candidate key there, so you might also require a synthetic primary key.

Then just have one or more composite indexes on the data, like

```
CREATE INDEX blah_t_country_region_idx
ON blah(t, type, country, region);
```

the order of columns is significant; it should go from most to least selective if all queries use all columns. Otherwise you should prefer to put the columns that the most queries use first.

You can create multiple indexes. PostgreSQL can also combine multiple indexes for a single query sometimes.

Remember that each index has a cost to insert/update and also uses disk space.

One option might be:

```
CREATE INDEX blah_t_country_region_idx
ON blah(t, type);
```

then separate indexes on `country` and `region`. Or multiple composite indexes, one on t+type+country, one on t+type+region, one on both. It all depends on how much you're willing to pay in disk space and I/O cost, and on your exact query patterns.

It's not really practical to suggest a more detailed strategy without knowing the query patterns and having some query `explain` data.

BTW, depending on the data source etc, you might want to make country and region foreign keys into lookup tables, rather than storing the literal strings.

Comment: I was considering that approach, but it doesn't meet my requirements: I need range queries for `t` and some other fields might be optional. In a basic btree composite index only the last parameter can be queried for a range. In this approach I would need to build a lot of "basic" indexes (in fact I have 2 more text fields then country and region). I wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: @RobertZaremba I already outlined an alternative for that - a common base index plus indexes on each individual attribute. Pg can then do bitmap index scans. It isn't as fast and can't use index-only scans but requires fewer and smaller (therefore faster to scan) indexes. Btw for `(a,b,c)` Pg can in fact use it for a query on a,c or b,c - it is just slower so Pg is less likely to choose it.

Comment: Yes, but I will not need to build 5 indexes. I'm wondering if there is - eg having some extra field specific for queries and use it with some gin index. Apart from that the idea with foreign keys for country / region is very good.

Comment: @RobertZaremba I expect you'll find such approaches slower, not faster. Infix search is slow. Array indexes are big and slow to update. So on.